.NET 8 - ValidConstructorNotFoundException: No valid constructor could be found
I am refactoring a classic .NET Framework App to .NET 8, and when I moved some classes into their own library I started getting a "No valid constructor could be found" error.
The error is being thrown on line 91 when WebTask.Wait() is called.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
Full details are as follows;
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=One or more errors occurred. (No valid constructor could be found for ACES_Core.DeceptionAPI+Agent)
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at ACES_Core.DeceptionAPI.GetAgent(HttpClient httpClient, String baseURI, String domain, String hostname, String dataset) in C:\Users\Administrator\Source\Repos\AC-EventServiceV2\ACES-Core\DeceptionAPI.cs:line 85
   at ACES_Core.MonitoredResources.FetchFromAPI(HttpClient httpClient, Config config, String agentDomain, String agentHostname) in C:\Users\Administrator\Source\Repos\AC-EventServiceV2\ACES-Core\MonitoredResources.cs:line 29
   at AC_EventService.ACESThread.Main() in C:\Users\Administrator\Source\Repos\AC-EventServiceV2\ACESThread.cs:line 95
   at AC_EventService.ACESThread..ctor() in C:\Users\Administrator\Source\Repos\AC-EventServiceV2\ACESThread.cs:line 60
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithNoArgs(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>d__15.MoveNext()

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    ACES_Core.DeceptionAPI.GetAgent.AnonymousMethod__0() in DeceptionAPI.cs

Inner Exception 1:
ValidConstructorNotFoundException: No valid constructor could be found for ACES_Core.DeceptionAPI+Agent


The custom ValidConstructorNotFoundException seems to be thrown on this line:
return _serializer.Deserialize<Agent[]>(response)[0];

As far as I have found out in the source code of Nancy.Json, the exception is thrown when a constructor cannot be found. The logic for it I found
var hasDefaultConstructor =
            t.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredConstructors.Any(ctor => !ctor.GetParameters().Any());

This always returns false for a struct that has not defined explicitly a parameterless constructor such as our Agent (which btw you now can under .NET 8)
Maybe you have changed Agent from class to struct?

Looking at the old code base it was a struct, so I am not sure why it worked before.

Changing the structs to classes fixed the problem. Thank you so much @ivan-petrov!
